# Overload resolution produces ambiguous call when template parameters added

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In the following code the compiler can successfully resolve the call to `f()` to call `f(int&, const char*)`.

The call to `g()`, however, is ambiguous.  It lists all four overloads as the possible overload set.  If I remove `, typename T2, std::size_t I` from the template argument list for the array argument, and hard code them instead, there is no ambiguity and the compiler picks `g(T&, const char*)`.

How is it that adding the two template arguments makes this ambiguous?  I can see how, though decay and casting, it could resolve to any one of the overloads, but I cannot figure out how adding those template parameters introduces the ambiguity.

I have testing this on Clang 3.8 (unreleased) and VC++ 2015.

```
#include <string>

void f(int&, const char*){}
void f(int&, char(&)[8]){}
void f(int&, bool){}
void f(int&, const std::string&){}

template <typename T>
void g(T&, bool){}
template <typename T>
void g(T&, const char*){}
template <typename T>
void g(T&, const std::string&){}
template <typename T, typename T2, std::size_t I>
void g(T&, T2(&)[I]){}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int i = 1;
   f(i, "       ");
   g(i, "       ");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload #2:

```
void g(T&, const char*){}
```

Overload #4:

```
template <typename T, typename T2, std::size_t I>
void g(T&, T2(&)[I]){}
```

Overload #2 and overload #4 will be ambiguous when calling `g(...)` with a string literal; the string literal argument will be deduced to `const char*` as well as `T2(&)[I]`.

**Reason**

Your string literal `"       "` is `const char[8]`, which clearly shows how it gets deduced to overload #4. However, since arrays decay to pointers, `const char[8]` is also `const char*` which clearly deduces to overload #2.

Comment: You are right.  I missed the `const` in the overload with the array.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler will usually list all possible overloads, not only the ambiguous ones. So there is no ambiguity regarding overloads 1 and 3. They are of second order. However, overloads 2 and 4 are of first order - string literal is an array, and array decaying is a the first order as well.